# How to change the font size in axis in Seaborn

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn

I don't know why I tried so many times and still failed in changing the font size on either the x-axis or the y-axis in the plot.

[image]

Also, there is a small title in the legend showing Gender Code(which is super small).

I tried

```
sns.set(font_scale=4)
```

Or

```
plt.rcParams["axes.labelsize"] = 20
```

But it doesn't make any sense. Is that because I used them in the wrong position?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for the font size on the x-and-axes of your plot, and if you're plotting your seaborn graph on a matplotlib axis (which you should be doing), you can do (with `axes` being the name of the axis):

```
for tick in axes.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tick.label.set_fontsize(10)

for tick in axes.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tick.label.set_fontsize(10)
```

For the font of the legend, you can try:

```
axes.legend(prop=dict(size=10))
```

Please tell if this does not solve your problem!

---

**EDIT**

With what you're giving as code, I guess you could do:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 9))

sns.boxplot(x="Benefits", y="Years In Job", hue="Gender Code", data = wk[(wk.Status=="A")], palette="Set3", ax=axes)

plt.title("Boxplot for Years In Job of Active Employees Under Different Benefit Types ", size=20, loc='right')

plt.xlabel("Benefit Type")

for tick in axes.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tick.label.set_fontsize(10)

for tick in axes.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tick.label.set_fontsize(10)

axes.legend(prop=dict(size=10))
```

Comment: plt.figure(figsize=(12,9))
sns.boxplot(x="Benefits",y="Years In Job",hue="Gender Code",data = wk[(wk.Status=="A")],palette="Set3")
plt.title("Boxplot for Years In Job of Active Employees Under Different Benefit Types ",size=20,loc='right')
plt.xlabel("Benefit Type")

Comment: I don't know how to apply for-loop in my current codes. And I didn't assign names for the axis.

Comment: I updated my answer to adapt it to your code - please tell me if it works now!

Answer (score 0):

**Add the below line to your code and it should increase the legend size**

```
ax.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=30)
```

Hope that helps